# How to prove any continous linear functional on c0 space can be uniquely extended to l_infinity space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I knew there are many solutions in stack for this, but i don't want to see that.I am actually seeking for some hint which actually invoke me to think such problems.
As $C_0 =\{(x_n):x_n \text{tends to} \ 0\}$ is a subspace of $l_{\infty}$ then i can extend it by Hahn Banach, but the extension may not be unique.How can i prove the unique extension, i have no idea. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $c_0$ is not dense, necessarily there are infinitely-many different extensions: for any fixed $v\in \ell^\infty$ not in $c_0$, extend a given functional on $c_0$ to that vector any way you like. Then invoke Hahn-Banach to extend to $\ell^\infty$. I do not know how to make a canonical choice from among the infinitely-many... but there maybe be some way.

Comment: @mihaild dear i knew this will answer my post but plz see my post actually i don't want to see any solution firstly.